# Laptop keyboard not working

Tags: laptop, keyboard

Few of the keys on my laptop's keyboard aren't working. A couple of days ago, I left my laptop running and forgot to shut it down. As a result it automatically shutdown due to low battery. The next day I noticed few of them weren't working. How do I fix it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, somewhere in this wide world a keyboard does not work! You don't know why. How should I know. Do you want an answer more useful than "find out what the problem is and fix it"?

Answer (score 1):

sometimes it happens because some static charge will left in the key board.
do the following steps.

1.Remove you'r laptop battery.

2.Do not plug it after removing battery press and hold power button for few seconds.

3.Plug it now and start you'r laptop and see the keys are working are not.

Comment: The issue is with laptop's keyboard, the external keyboard is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

The same has happened with my laptop Fujitsu Lifebook series..... I researched about this on the internet only in vain...
The following are the things i tried - which you can also try (might work for you)
1. Remove your laptop battery - Turn on your laptop with main power on and shutdown
2. Uninstall your keyboard driver and re-install the driver.
I assume you would have tried the famous re-start of PC option

Comment: I will give it a try,did it work for you?
Do you know why this happens at all?

Comment: For a colleague of mine, it was a few non-working keys in beginning followed by total keyboard failure.... In my case its only a few keys that are working. I have tried the above steps and resorted to warranty from Fujitsu as the final step. Looks like a hardware issue to me....

Answer (score 0):

1. Restart your PC
2. Uninstall keyboard driver and re-install it
3. Press <kbd>Num Lock</kbd>
4. Get a USB Keyboard

[I shared my experience here too on this post](http://www.netsocialblog.com/2017/04/how-to-fix-keyboard-not-working-properly.html)

Comment: You might add more detail to #2 when you get a chance.

Answer (score -1):

I had the Same issue few months ago.
(Hope it might help you )
1. Try any cleaner like c cleaner or other cleaner to remove Junk.
2. Reinstall the compatible Driver.
3. Remove Keyboard and clean the socket and try again.
4. Try your keyboard at a friend's same Laptop..
5. Last Option ...Give your laptop to Authorized service station for repair

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you to first restart your laptop. If the issue still occur, then update or re-install keyboard drivers.

You can also get some help from here:

http://laptopify.com/laptop-keyboard-not-working-solution/